# jQuery Masonry - y position

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

I have a problem with the script jQuery Masonry.
It's about stacking boxes - currently arranges them horizontally, limited to the width. Chciałym however limited to the level and lined up the same way in the level, allowing horizontal scrolling.
I have no idea how to do it, from what I saw there is no such a solution on their website